# Clone RDS aurora Database with AWS lambda function

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I'm building a SaaS product with tenancy per database (each client has it's own RDS Aurora mysql compatible db)

When creating a new client account I would like to clone a template database (schema+data) into the new client's database. Ideally, I would trigger this from a C# AWS lambda function.

- Is this feasible?
- Could I somehow use the mysqldump binary for this? Maybe other binary?

NOTE: The clone must happen within the same RDS Aurora instance (Not creating a new separate RDS instance)

Thank you

Comment: When you say database, are you referring to a schema within the instance?

Comment: @AllanChua yes,  a schema within the instance